# Why is Histogram of Oriented Gradients only 0 to 180 degrees and not 0 to 360 degrees?

Tags: computer-vision, histogram

Why is Histogram of Oriented Gradients only 0 to 180 degrees and not 0 to 360 degrees?

I can see in many videos that it's very common that `atan` which results values between `0` to `180`. The function `atan2` is not used, in `HOG`, which results values between `-180` and `+180`.

**Question:**

If only the half circle is taken to account, then we will lose lots of information about the descriptor. So why did some consider that would be a better solution, than taking with the complete circle?

Sources:

- [Feature Engineering for Images: A Valuable Introduction to the HOG Feature Descriptor](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/09/feature-engineering-images-introduction-hog-feature-descriptor/)
- [Lecture 9.3: Features [Histogram of Gradients] [HOG]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92-NaIdIrEs&t=549s&ab_channel=UCFCRCV)